# How to parse JSON using hardocoded values

Tags: android, parsing, json

I am trying to parse json but it gives me exception.

I hardcoded expected json as String like this

```
  String stringJSON="[{\"value1\":\"ABC567123\",\"end_at\":\"08/28/2014 09:10:00\",\"start_at\":\"04/25/2016 09:20:00\"}]";
```

Valid json is like this

```
[
{
    "value1": "ABC567123",
    "end_at": "08/28/2014 09:10:00",
    "start_at": "04/25/2016 09:20:00"
}
]
```

Now I am trying to parse json like below and getting exception.

```
JSONObject responseObJ;
    try {
        responseObJ= new JSONObject(stringJSON); //error here
        if(responseObJ!=null){
             //do something 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Please suggest what to do?
//hard coded it for temporary - json result is expected to exact same

Comment: your JSON response start with JSONArray not with JSONObject, thats why its giving error

Comment: Ya Remove [] from stringJSON. ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringJSON` is contains `JSONArray`  instead of `JSONObject` as root element in JSON String.

Either remove `[]` from start and end of String according to current code or if multiple JSONObject's is available in JSONArray then get `JSONArray` from `stringJSON` :

```
JSONArray responseObJ= new JSONArray(stringJSON);
```

Answer (score 3):

[ ] they show that it has an array of objects in it so you can retrieve it like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(stringJSON);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

    // here you can get the values of objects stored in the jsonObject
}
```

In your case you have only one object so you don't have to use loop instead you can get it like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(stringJSON);
JSONObject jsonObject = jObject.getJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

yes as you said its valid json but its `JsonArray` not `JsonObject`.
Just remove [] from start and end.

your string should be

```
String stringJSON="{\"value1\":\"ABC567123\",\"end_at\":\"08/28/2014 09:10:00\",\"start_at\":\"04/25/2016 09:20:00\"}";
```

or if you want to work with current string then use `JsonArray` instead of `JsonObject`

```
JSONArray responseObJ= new JSONArray(stringJSON);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Ravi Rupareliya

Answer (score 1):

Can you try Deserialize method of ScriptSerializer class? Like:

```
        var scriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var obj = scriptSerializer.Deserialize<Object>(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion @rorfun

Comment: This must be comment ! !